# Azure Blob Storage to VM Folder

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, blob

I have a Azure VM and I am able to RDP its public IP address. However when I am trying to create a pipeline from Azure Blob to VM folder it is not getting accessed from outside the VM. I have already configured the rules for the ICMP for VM OS and network security group.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what do you mean by pipeline? And what does ICMP have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved after installing  and configuring the Intergration runtime (Formerly Data Management Gateway) on the VM. Could create a pipeline from Azure Blob to VM Folder.